# Missing punctuation and the tense usage

Tags: grammar, punctuation, tenses, headline-english

I have written the following sentence as a headline for an invitation email.

> ABC Ltd. welcomes you to Exhibition Dubai 2017 held at the Dubai World
>   Trade Center from June 7 to June 9, 2017.

Am I missing a punctuation mark after 2017? Should I change the verb form of "held"?

I want it to be brief. I want to know the mistakes in this sentence, please!

Comment: It being a heading, **ABC Ltd. welcomes you to "The Exhibition Dubai 2017" from June 7 to 9 at Dubai World Trade Center** will do.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a punctuation" on English because it is a mass noun not a count noun.

Comment: Got it, tchrist! I should have written a **punctuation mark** instead.

Comment: @tchrist Is it okay if I use "held" in the sentence. I apologize for I am sure you have a busy soul to tend to such trivial questions.

Comment: @Shantaram I suppose. It comes off as a little odd because it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Please do not use "the below" to mean simply "this" or "the following".  Please avoid using "the below" altogether as it sounds wrong to many native speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if you consider it a [restrictive clause](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/comma#commas_to_separate_clauses). If yes, you don't need a comma here.

> Basically, a restrictive relative clause contains information that’s essential to the meaning of the sentence as a whole. If you left it out, the sentence wouldn’t make much sense.

I don't think this applies because you also mention the title, so the place and time is additional information.

The perfect tense is technically incorrect because it has not taken place yet. So you could use ", which will be held at..." instead. Note that this distinguishes the date and place as supporting information instead of the main information even more and makes one wonder why it made it into the headline.

For the sake of brevity however, I think your version would also be ok.